# How to run Angular versions 8 and 13 in parallel

Tags: angular

I read somewhere that upgrading from version 8 to 13 is impossible, therefore I looked into the micro-frontend.

However, I have yet to come across any instances that meet my requirements.

Where can I get information on how to use micro-frontend in my project?
My project now uses Angular 8, however I'd like to switch to Angular 13 for development.
I can't work on changing the modules to the new version because the project has too many at the time.

Can I use version 13 to develop my project while still using version 8 components, services, and directives?

**It's clear that the components of version 13 will be wrapped with pages from version 8.**

Comment: "I read somewhere that upgrading from version 8 to 13 is impossible" – That source was wrong. Of course you can upgrade from 8 to 13.

Comment: Yes, my presentation could be inaccurate; nevertheless, if I upgrade, I'll have a lot of shared module issues to address with my existing project, and I don't have the time or resources to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I only assume you want to work in parallel in order to use 2 apps that built over different versions

If that is your case - let me suggest an alternative - convert your old (and probably unsafe code) to a newer one! It's pretty transparent when using the Angular official *Update Guide*.

In your case - https://update.angular.io/?v=8.0-13.0

I know - the TODO list seems endless and some tasks are WAY harder than other (it also depends on your project implementation as well) but on the bright side - you have a guided process that ensures you that after all is completed - you are good to go

In any other case you will end up with a hybrid app that host multiple apps (usually build over different frameworks) and you will need to implement communication between then (hence, main app is for hosting purposes and communications only)

Since you already using Angular I (in person) thinks that the benefit of this *one time operation* exceeded the "benefit" of cutting time and costs (for now) only to suffer from poor performance and delivering starting the very near future

The choice is yours - I hope it will end-up as well as possible

Comment: Thanks for the advice; sometimes the client is still the most important factor; I have no choice but to find the most cost-effective solution without having to spend a lot of money to make little profit.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. *For what it worth:* if the client will see this upgrade as a long-term cost-effective strategy - decision (any hopefully budget) will change as well. Sometimes the only tool missing in our toolbox is a truly good argument that can change it all